# Dark mode switch onclick and not page switch

Tags: javascript, darkmode

I have this particular function in js that toggles the css darkmode function on a button onclick event present in the navbar. But it resets as soon as a page is switched.

```
var $light_switch = 1;

function switchMode() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    document.body.style = "transition: all 2s;";
    if($light_switch == 0) {
        document.getElementById("lights").innerHTML = "Enable Dark Mode";
        document.getElementById("lights").style = "background-color: #f5f5f5; color: #121212; ";
        $light_switch = 1;
    }else {
        document.getElementById("lights").innerHTML = "Disable Dark Mode";
        document.getElementById("lights").style = "background-color: #121212; color: #f5f5f5; ";
        $light_switch = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("lights").style = " transition: all 2s;";
}
```

Any ideas on how i can modify the js code to make sure dark mode once enabled doesn't turn off until a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localStorage API to store the user's preference for dark mode and then apply the saved setting when the page is loaded.Try this

```
    function switchMode() {
    var $light_switch = localStorage.getItem("light_switch") === "1" ? 1 : 0;
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    document.body.style = "transition: all 2s;";

    if ($light_switch == 0) {
        document.getElementById("lights").innerHTML = "Enable Dark Mode";
        document.getElementById("lights").style = "background-color: #f5f5f5; color: #121212; ";
        localStorage.setItem("light_switch", 1);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("lights").innerHTML = "Disable Dark Mode";
        document.getElementById("lights").style = "background-color: #121212; color: #f5f5f5; ";
        localStorage.setItem("light_switch", 0);
    }
    document.getElementById("lights").style = " transition: all 2s;";
}

// Initialize the mode when the page is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var $light_switch = localStorage.getItem("light_switch");
    if ($light_switch === "0") {
        switchMode();
    }
});
```

it stores the $light_switch in the browser's localStorage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).